# onChange event not firing when input changed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my form, I have a DropDown, when a value is selected, I fire some JavaScript that populates some visible `<input type="text" />` fields (under neath the drop down).

The problem is, I also want to run some JavaScript function whenever the value of one of these inputs changes, I want this function to run even if the text input is changed by the drop down selection.

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainPane').on('change', '#formElementFromEmail', function(event){
        var collectFromDropDown = $('#formElementFromEmail');
        persistHiddenInputForCollectFromValue();
    });
});
```

I suspect the change event is not being fired because no one has manually changed the value of the field in question. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Try `blur` event instead of `change` on input field.

Comment: you can use keyup,also your question is not clear

Comment: I hope it is clearer now. I tried `blue` .. and got same thing, not firing. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can trigger the event:

`$('#mainPane').trigger('change');`

Answer (score 3):

you can simulate change event by

```
var element = document.getElementById('formElementFromEmail');
element.onchange();
```

Comment: You mean if I call the `onchange();` that fires an onchange event?

Comment: @helion, gives you same way in jQuery, you can consider his answer also